# Javascript for loop runs only twice

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var toBeHidden_letter = document.getElementsByClassName('doc_direction');
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    toBeHidden_letter[i].style.display = 'block';
    alert('i = '+i);
}
```

I only have 2 alerts. why?

Edited : I have 10 elements of class = 'doc_direction' in my HTML.

Comment: Show your HTML. My guess would be you only have 2 elements which match the class. After this, the javascript is returning a reference error

Comment: Are you sure that you have 10 elements with the class "doc_direction"? If you have only 2, the for-loop runs twice and then fails because there is no third index in toBeHidden_letter.

Comment: Open your JavaScript console and check if you are getting any errors. I suspect that `getElementsByClassName` only returns 2 elements, and so your loop will error out on the third iteration ...

Comment: Does it throw any error? How can you be sure that you have 10 items in the collection? You would be much better to loop using the length of the list returned, not a static number.

Comment: I have 10 elements of class = 'doc_direction'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need :

```
var toBeHidden_letter = document.getElementsByClassName('doc_direction');
for(var i = 0; i < toBeHidden_letter.length; i++) {
    toBeHidden_letter[i].style.display = 'block';
    alert('i = '+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have only two elements with `.doc_direction` class name and JS causes errors, can you check console for errors and provide some HTML?

BTW better is to get length of elements instead of hardcoded number 10:

```
for(var i = 0; i < toBeHidden_letter.length; i++) {
```